# MySQLi Connection Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having some trouble getting MySQLi to connect and respond properly. It should be relaying a connection error any time it is unable to connect to the database, but it doesn't, even when  enter invalid details in an attempt to force a connection error.

```
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if ($emailaddress&&$password)
    {
        $db = new mysqli('loalhost','rot','','FitessHouse');
        if($db->connect_errno > 0)  
        {
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Let me be more clear. I am *trying* to get MySQLi to return a connection error because the connection fails. I'm not trying to fix the connection. When I hit "Submit" it takes me to a blank page, which means my die statement is not working.

Fixed it and now have this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: emailaddress in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FitnessHouse/login.php on line 5

Comment: *> it takes me to a blank page, which means my die statement is not working.* Actually it means only that you see a blank page. And there could be 1000 reasons for that To be sure that your die statement is not working, you have to add an else condition, to prove that. though I am sure it won't be run too

Comment: Duplicate of [Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)

Comment: Please paste the relevant code from pastebin to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code should display the error and stop the script:

```
$db = new mysqli('loalhost','rot','','FitessHouse')
    or die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
```

You can also use [trigger_error](http://php.net/trigger_error) instead of [die](http://php.net/die):

```
$db = new mysqli('loalhost','rot','','FitessHouse');
if($db->connect_errno)
    trigger_error('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']', E_USER_ERROR);
```